# Develop sharepoint software without having local sharepoint installation

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there anyway to develop sharepoint projects without having sharepoint server installed locally. I have a sharepoint server running at my work and vs2010 installed locally. I want to be able to test my projects on the server.

Comment: This question has been asked and answer many times. See Related down the left hand side for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You develop them locally but without SharePoint installed you cant test them. Microsoft Offers no free version of SharePoint Server, so you have to be able to use a licensed copy of SharePoint to test on it. I just use a Remote Desktop Connection to connect to my DEV machine that has SP installed on and Visual Studio. I then develop my app then test, and then it gets deployed to our SharePoint Farm.

Comment: [Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49c79a8a-4612-4e7d-a0b4-3bb429b46595&displaylang=en) is available as a free download.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to build wsp and then deploy it on a SharePoint server. I hope, this links will help you:

[Creating a SharePoint Solution Package (.wsp) in 5 steps](http://geekswithblogs.net/evgenyblog/archive/2008/01/27/118966.aspx)

[WSPBuilder (SharePoint WSP tool)](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/)

[Installation and Deployment of a Farm Solution in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544500.aspx)